# Having difficulty configuring php debugging using netbeans

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

**UPDATE 2:**

Nevermind, figured it out, in netbeans I had an extra `)` in `tools > options > general > web browser > edit > arguments` was `-remote {url})`, so I changed it to `-remote {url}`.

I now have netbeans debugging php on my new laptop.

**UPDATE 1:**

I've been comparing my old laptop with my new laptop as debugging works on my old laptop.  The only difference I have seen is the url in the browser when I click debug.

Old laptop:
`http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug`

New laptop:
`http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug)`

When I remove the ending `)` from the new laptop url manually, debugging starts to work...  Why does the new laptop setup have an ')' at the end and the old setup doesn't?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm trying to configure xdebug for php debugging via netbeans on a localhost.  I have tried following a couple of guides, but can't seem to get it to work.  I've had it configured on an old laptop, but can't seem to remember how.  At the moment, when I add a breakpoint and click "debug project", it opens up a browser and displays `waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)`.  The "step over" and "step into" options are disabled.

How do I resolve this issue?

I have done the following so far:

I have installed lamp, php5-xdebug, and the php plugin for netbeans.

I have the following in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

I have done `service apache2 restart`.

I can see that `xdebug` is enabled with `phpinfo();`

In netbeans - tools > options > php, I have done the following:

```
PHP 5 Interpreter = /usr/bin/php
Bebugger Port = 9000
Session ID = netbeans-xdebug
```

Comment: Please see updated question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem can be seen in update 2 in the original question, which is:

In netbeans I had an extra `)` in `tools > options > general > web browser > edit > arguments` was `-remote {url})`, so I changed it to `-remote {url}`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like netbeans is waiting for php to callback. Did you add xdebug to php?

For more info see [this article](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug)

Comment: Yes, I have installed php5-xdebug and restarted apache.  Please see my updated question to see everything I have done.

Comment: Looks all okay, though modifying both php.ini and xdebug.ini is a bit double I don't think that's the problem. You might want to try replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1, I have seen cases where localhost resolved to the ipv6 address while the server side was only listening on ipv4.